# INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED when run android automation test from sh

Tags: sh, instrumentation

I'm doing automation test for an android app. My test code is ready and good to run from android studio and manual command from android device.  But when I change the command to sh, it failed with INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED. Anyone can help me how to fix it? I just don't understand, why it's working when directly run from terminal, but failed when run from sh.

Manual input comment, which is working:

```
am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class com.amap.auto.androidautomation.testcases.basemap.SmokeTest com.amap.auto.androidautomation.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Result:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=9
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
com.amap.auto.androidautomation.testcases.basemap.SmokeTest:
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=AndroidJUnitRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=smoke01
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.amap.auto.androidautomation.testcases.
```

Run from sh:(the command is the same as manual, just put it in a sh file)

```
sh r.sh
```

Result:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: Component
Info{com.amap.auto.androidautomation.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUn
}tRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.amap.auto.androidauto
mation.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:1093)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:371)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:100)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:251)
: not foundnload/r.sh[2]: exit
```

Comment: I installed terminal in the android device to run the command.  If ran from android studio directly after connect the android device, running is also working.

Comment: I have resolved this issue.  Just remove the /n/r in the end of the script.  I included the windows char in the sh file.